# how to get aws credentials from host workstation, inside docker container

Tags: amazon-web-services, credentials

I am trying to get my AWS credentials into my Docker container for use on my local (for development). I found this article, https://cameroneckelberry.co/words/getting-aws-credentials-into-a-docker-container-without-hardcoding-it, but I have no idea how to "create an AWS shell script" or what `-profile` is. I don't see that on my system. Yes, I do have AWS CLI installed and also have put my `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and my `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` into my `.env` file. I have also put my credentials into `$home/.aws/credentials` as requested, but can't see how that has any affect on the env variables. From the article:

> Running $ aws help we see there is a –profile parameter. Leveraging
> this, we can write a shell script to get our credentials into our
> Docker container.
>
> AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$(aws --profile default configure get
> aws_access_key_id) AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$(aws --profile default
> configure get aws_secret_access_key)
>
> docker build -t my_app . docker run -it --rm \    -e
> AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID \    -e
> AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY

If someone could explain exactly what to do, as if speaking to a child, I would appreciate it.

Comment: You want to be able to use your aws credentials from host workstation, inside docker container?

Comment: Yes, that is the goal.

Answer (score 3):

I think the easiest way would be to do what AWS is doing when they show how to use local containers with AWS services, such as for [local AWS Glue](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/building-an-aws-glue-etl-pipeline-locally-without-an-aws-account/). Namely they share the `~/.aws/` in **read-only** mode with the docker container using [volume](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#volume-shared-filesystems) option:

```
-v ~/.aws:/root/.aws:ro
```

Obviously you would have to adjust the paths above to match your local and docker setup. Thus your docker command could be:

```
docker run -it --rm -v ~/.aws:/root/.aws:ro <name-of-image-to-run>
```

The other way is to pass the AWS credentials using docker environment variables, which you already are trying.

Regarding `--profile`. Your `~/.aws` can have multiple [profiles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-profiles.html), e.g. for different AWS accounts. Using the `--profile` you specify which profile to use.

Comment: Thx. I am not using docker run , just my docker-compose. Where does docker run go?

Comment: @band You question does not say that you are using docker-compose? Anyway you can check [here](https://devopsheaven.com/docker/docker-compose/volumes/2018/01/16/volumes-in-docker-compose.html) how to use volumes in compose.